# latexmk seems to miss the last, required rerun of *latex

Tags: luatex, texlive, latexmk

I am using TeX Live 2023, TeX 3.141592653, LuaHBTeX 1.16.0, Latexmk 4.79 on Windows 10.

**Short description:**
I have a MWE that compiles without problems by doing `lualatex -> biber -> lualatex -> lualatex`. When using `latexmk -lualatex` the last run of lualatex does not happen. If calling `lualatex` afterwards again, everything works out.

MWE Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../Literatur/literatur_test.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
Citation 1 \cite{Aas2021} and a label \label{test_label}

\section{Another Section}
Citation 2 \cite{Lundberg2017} and a reference \ref{test_label}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Relevant part of the `.bib` file:

```
@Article{Aas2021,
  author       = {Kjersti Aas and Martin Jullum and Anders L{\o}land},
  date         = {2021},
  journaltitle = {Artificial Intelligence},
  title        = {Explaining individual predictions when features are dependent: More accurate approximations to Shapley values},
  doi          = {10.1016/j.artint.2021.103502},
  pages        = {103502},
  volume       = {298},
  abstract     = {Explaining complex or seemingly simple machine learning models is an important practical problem. We want to explain individual predictions from such models by learning simple, interpretable explanations. Shapley value is a game theoretic concept that can be used for this purpose. The Shapley value framework has a series of desirable theoretical properties, and can in principle handle any predictive model. Kernel SHAP is a computationally efficient approximation to Shapley values in higher dimensions. Like several other existing methods, this approach assumes that the features are independent. Since Shapley values currently suffer from inclusion of unrealistic data instances when features are correlated, the explanations may be very misleading. This is the case even if a simple linear model is used for predictions. In this paper, we extend the Kernel SHAP method to handle dependent features. We provide several examples of linear and non-linear models with various degrees of feature dependence, where our method gives more accurate approximations to the true Shapley values.},
  day          = {31},
  keywords     = {Feature attribution, Shapley values, Kernel SHAP, Dependence},
  publisher    = {Elsevier {BV}},
  year         = {2021},
}

@InProceedings{Lundberg2017,
  author    = {Lundberg, Scott and Lee, Su-In},
  booktitle = {Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems},
  date      = {2017},
  title     = {A unified approach to interpreting model predictions},
  pages     = {4765--4774},
}
```

**Manual attempt**: I cleaned up everything, there is only the `.tex` file in the directory. Calling `lualatex` on that gives (excerpt):

```
[...]
No file Main.toc.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Aas2021' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Lundberg2017' on page 1 undefined on input line 14.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `test_label' on page 1 undefined on input line 14.

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 16.

[1{c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
] (./Main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `Main.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                Main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
[...]
```

Running `biber` gives only a warning about `8 characters of junk seen at toplevel`.

Running `lualatex` again gives (excerpt):

```
[...]
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.
[...]
```

Running `lualatex` for the third time in total produces no warning and leads to the expected result in a PDF file.

**`latexmk` attempt**: I cleaned up everything, there is only the `.tex` file in the directory. When running `latexmk -lualatex` the expected behavior is, that it runs `lualatex` and `biber` as often as needed. Produced output (full):

```
    L:[...]\Dokument>latexmk --lualatex
Initial Win CP for (console input, console output, system): (CP437, CP437, CP1252)
I changed them all to CP1252
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 7 Jan. 2023. Version 4.79.
No existing .aux file, so I'll make a simple one, and require run of *latex.
Latexmk: applying rule 'lualatex'...
Rule 'lualatex':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'lualatex' forced or previously required

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'lualatex'
------------
------------
Running 'lualatex  -recorder  "Main.tex"'
------------
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./Main.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2022/10/12 v3.38 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.
sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty)))
 (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.cl
o)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty))
 (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.st
y
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
 (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-unicode.def)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)
) (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx
) (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex
.def))
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.st
y
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.s
ty)))
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekey
s.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
 (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.st
y) (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitles
tring.sty))
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.st
y)) (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty)
) (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hluatex.def
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
 (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilech
eck.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecoun
ter.sty))) (./Main.aux)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
No file Main.bbl.
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bookmark.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bkm-pdftex.def))
No file Main.toc.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Aas2021' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Lundberg2017' on page 1 undefined on input line 14.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `test_label' on page 1 undefined on input line 14.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 16.

[1{c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
] (./Main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.


Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `Main.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                Main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

)
 491 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 65 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:2,2:135,3:75,4:4,5:42,6:15,7:562,9:99,10:1,11:42
<c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-b
old.otf><c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmr
oman10-regular.otf><c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/pu
blic/lm/lmsans10-bold.otf>
Output written on Main.pdf (1 page, 10772 bytes).
Transcript written on Main.log.
Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'Main.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'Main.log'
Latexmk: Missing bbl file 'Main.bbl' in following:
 No file Main.bbl.
Latexmk: Missing input file 'Main.toc' (or dependence on it) from following:
  No file Main.toc.
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'Main.pdf'
Latexmk: Bibliography file(s) form .bcf file:
  ../Literatur/literatur_test.bib
Latexmk: applying rule 'biber Main'...
Rule 'biber Main':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'biber Main' forced or previously required

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'biber Main'
------------
------------
Running 'biber  "Main.bcf"'
------------
INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is 'Main.blg'
INFO - Reading 'Main.bcf'
INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex file '../Literatur/literatur_test.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source '../Literatur/literatur_test.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nty' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'Main.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to Main.bbl
Latexmk: Found biber source file(s) [../Literatur/literatur_test.bib Main.bcf]
Latexmk: applying rule 'lualatex'...
Rule 'lualatex':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  Main.aux
  Main.bbl
  Main.toc

------------
Run number 2 of rule 'lualatex'
------------
------------
Running 'lualatex  -recorder  "Main.tex"'
------------
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./Main.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2022/10/12 v3.38 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.
sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty)))
 (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.cl
o)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty))
 (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.st
y
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
 (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-unicode.def)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)
) (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx
) (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex
.def))
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.st
y
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.s
ty)))
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekey
s.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
 (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.st
y) (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitles
tring.sty))
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.st
y)) (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty)
) (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hluatex.def
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
 (c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilech
eck.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecoun
ter.sty))) (./Main.aux)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
(./Main.bbl) (./Main.out) (./Main.out)
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bookmark.sty
(c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bkm-pdftex.def))
(./Main.toc) [1{c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updma
p/pdftex.map}] (./Main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.

)
 506 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 68 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:2,2:333,3:229,4:4,5:111,6:36,7:2309,8:28,9:195,10:2,11:198
<c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmmono10-re
gular.otf><c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/l
mromancaps10-regular.otf><c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opent
ype/public/lm/lmroman10-italic.otf><c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/texmf-dist/f
onts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf><c:/MeineProgramme/TeXLive/2023/t
exmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-bold.otf>
Output written on Main.pdf (1 page, 21098 bytes).
Transcript written on Main.log.
Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'Main.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'Main.log'
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'Main.bbl'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'Main.pdf'
Latexmk: Bibliography file(s) form .bcf file:
  ../Literatur/literatur_test.bib
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  lualatex: gave an error
----------------------
This message may duplicate earlier message.
Latexmk: Failure in processing file 'Main.tex':
   *LaTeX didn't generate the expected log file 'Main.log'
----------------------

Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (437,437)
C:\MeineProgramme\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:921: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:\MeineProgramme\TeXLive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl --lualatex
```

The output shows errors, but the produced PDF seems to be fine. When running `lualatex` again now, it runs without problems or errors.

Is it a problem of `lualatex` to request a third run at the end or is it correct to run three times and `latexmk` falsely does not fulfill this request of `lualatex`?

**Edit after update of latexmk:**

After updating to latexmk 4.80 everything worked without errors. There is only the warning

```
Latexmk: I am working around an offset relative to my system time by
   -38 secs for file times in directory ''.
   This **probably** indicates that 
   (a) I (latexmk) am running on one computer, while the filesystem is
       hosted on a different computer/
   (b) There is a substantial time offset between system times on the two
       computers.
   (c) Therefore at least one of the computers has a misconfigured operating
       system such that its system time is not correctly synchronized with a
       time server.
   These issues are likely to cause problems with other software, and any
   such operating-system misconfigurations should be corrected.  By default
   current operating systems are configured to correctly synchronize system
   time when they are connected to the Internet
```

This is probably the case because I am working with an file server that seems to have the time set differently.

Comment: latexmk says you had errors so it skipped the last run `Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets`   but you haven't shown source and only fragments of log so we can't say if that's right or wrong

Comment: I tried your code with a correct bib file, using `latexmk -lualatex` (latexmk version 4.80). Everything worked fine. Maybe your bib file has a problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added the full output of latexmk now. You said I had not shown source, I assume you mean the .bib file? At least I added that, too.

@hair-splitter Thanks for trying it out. I added my bib file and assume it to be correct. And if it were a problem of the bib file, wouldn't the manual run `lualatex -> biber -> lualatex*2` have problems too?

Comment: @e_equals_pi, The `latexmk -lualatex` works well for me with your bib file as well.

Comment: @hair-splitter, how many runs of lualatex are done after the biber run in your case? One or two?

Comment: @e_equals_pi, One

Comment: @hair-splitter, thanks again for trying. Which OS and LaTeX distribution do you use? I am asking because I had no problems with the same files on Manjaro Linux with TeX Live. But as latexmk is a Perl script and Windows has no full Perl, I am thinking of that as a possible source of problems.

Comment: @e_equals_pi, Windows10, TeX Live 2023

Comment: @hair-splitter I really do not see where this problem could come from then

Comment: @e_equals_pi: I tried running latexmk on your example with TeXLive 2023 on Windows (WIndows 11 on ARM to be precise).  It worked fine.  The only anomaly was that lualatex was run a 4th time.  (Latexmk said that this was because of a change in Main.run.xml; I may to fix that.)   It also worked equally well on macOS.

Comment: @e_equals_pi: I see three anomalies in your output: (a) Your output pdf file has 2 pages; mine only has 1. So your MWE **appears** not to be the one for which you showed output. (b) Latexmk reports `Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made.`  But lualatex was run with the `-recorder` option, and succeeded in producing the .log file, so it should have produced the file Main.fls.  Do you see it? (c) At the end latexmk reports: `*LaTeX didn't generate the expected log file 'Main.log'`.  This appears to contradict its success in `Examining 'Main.log'`. **Continued in next comment**

Comment: @e_equals_pi: The items in my previous comment indicate that there is something peculiar in your system and how it is set up.  Questions: (1) Did an fls file actually get made? (2) The CLI prompt in your listing shows apparently the use of a drive L.  Is this on a remote server?  (3) Please show an output listing from latexmk that results from running it with the .tex and .bib files those are **exactly** those shown in the problem.

Comment: @e_equals_pi: The fact that Windows TeXLive does not have a full Perl doesn't matter.  TeXLive's Perl is all that's needed for latexmk.

Comment: All: Latexmk both says it could not find the .log file and that it analyzed the log file.  I checked the code: Latexmk analyzes the log file simply if the file exists and can be read.  But the check for whether a file was generated on the current run of *latex also involves the time stamp of the .log file relative to the time of the run.  There are problems if files are on an external server whose current clock time mismatches that on the local computer. There was a correction about this in v. 4.80.  So **update TeXLive** before going further. (Me: improve warnings in latexmk.)

Comment: @JohnCollins thank you so much! You were absolutely right about the remote server and the timestamp problem (see the edit / added output). You were also right about me showing the wrong output, I had pre-formatted it in a text editor and mixed it up there, sorry! Yes, the .fls file exists. Yes L is a remote server. I updated the outputs generated with latexmk 4.79, still had the problem, then I updated to latexmk 4.80 and it works without an error. I also added the output after the update to 4.80, it confirms what you said about the time. Thank you!

Comment: I can work out an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Puzzles in output:**
Near the end of the output listing, latexmk says that it didn't complete processing because there were errors.  That's enough to explain why too few runs of lualatex were made.

However, the reported error was that the expected log file wasn't made.  That seems contradictory, since two runs of lualatex were successful, and necessarily generated a log file.  There's also a warning the the fls file was not made, even though a successful run of lualatex with the -recorder option would have generated the file.  Moreover the OP had no problem running lualatex and biber separately.

So the error report from latexmk implies that there is some anomaly, but it must be of a strange kind.  (And the error message could be more helpful.)

**Resolution:**
It turns out that this problem had already been reported, and latexmk updated to v. 4.80.  Simply updating TeXLive was enough to get latexmk to compile the document correctly.  It also provided a message, quoted at the end of the edited question, about a mismatch of the system clocks on the computer running latexmk and the computer hosting the source files of the document.  As explained in the message, that mismatch should be corrected.

That leaves the oddity of why that problem with the system clocks should have caused trouble with the previous version of latexmk.

**What went wrong:**
After a run of *latex, latexmk gets dependency information from the .fls and .log files.  Under certain misconfigurations or under certain error conditions, the files may fail to be generated, or generated in the wrong directory, or with the wrong name.  In that case files with the expected names may exist but be relics from a previous run.  Latexmk has to detect this situation, otherwise it gets out-of-date dependency information, which messes up its functioning.

Now the modification time of an relic file will be earlier than that of the new run of *latex.  So latexmk asks whether or not the modification times were earlier than the run time, and if they are earlier it concludes that the files are relics of an earlier run and weren't generated on the latest run.  Hence the error message.  (The logic of how latexmk deals with this wasn't fully correct, so latexmk ran lualatex twice instead of stopping after the first run.)

With a mismatch of system clocks, the generated files can look as if they were generated before the run of lualatex started.  The current version of latexmk does a measurement of the mismatch when needed, so it can work correctly.